# $f>0$ on $[0,1]$ implies $\int_0^1 f >0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Someone made the remark on my old question (second-to-last comment on the answer from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873555/show-there-exists-x-in-0-1-such-that-fx-leq-int-01-ft-dt)) that a integrable function $f>0$ on $[0,1]$ does not imply $\int_0^1 f >0$ since
 limits do not preserve strict inequality. But I think it is true and I will try to give a proof.

Since $\{f>0\} = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{f>\frac{1}{n}\}$, from continuity of Lebesgue measure 
$$ 1= m(\{f>0\}) = m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big\{f>\frac{1}{n}\Big\}\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} m\left(\Big\{f>\frac{1}{n}\Big\}\right),$$
this means there exists $N$ such that  $m\left(\Big\{f>\frac{1}{N}\Big\}\right)\geq 1/2$.

Then $\frac{1}{N}\chi_{\{f>\frac{1}{N}\}} \leq f$ and 
$$\int_0^1 f \geq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{N}\chi_{\{f>\frac{1}{N}\}} \geq \frac{1}{2N} > 0.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You are 100% correct. More generally, if $f \neq 0$ on a set $E$ of positive measure, then $|f| > 0$ on $E$, and the same proof implies that $\int |f| > 0$. Conversely, if $f = 0$ a.e., then $\int |f| = 0$. Rephrasing in terms of the $L^1$ norm, we have $\|f\|_1 = 0$ if and only if $f = 0$ a.e.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. The two comments on that old answer are wrong. The first comment says:

> The above proof is wrong: if $f(x)>C$ then $\int_0^1 f(x) \mathbb{d}x \geq C$. Notice that the inequality becomes non-strict, because integration is just passing to the limit and limits do not preserve the strictness of inequalities.

It is generally a good rule that limits do not preserve strict inequalities. But this user in his or her comment is wrong that this holds for *integrals* in particular. In fact, for the Lebesgue (or Riemann!) integral, if $f > g$ on a set $A$, and both are integrable, then $\int_A f > \int_A g$.

Specifically, let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set, and suppose $f, g$ are measurable, with $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x \in A$. Then $\int_A f > \int_A g$, with just a few exceptions:

- If $A$ has measure $0$, this won't hold.
- If $\int_A f = -\infty$ or if $\int_A g = \infty$, this won't hold.

This covers the Riemann case as well, since Riemann integrable functions are also Lebesgue integrable. (Except for some improper Riemann integrals -- I'm not sure if it holds in the case of improper integrals or not.)

---

This has also been covered on mathSE a lot of times. Some examples: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777827/proof-that-the-integral-of-a-positive-function-is-positive), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693153/show-that-the-integral-of-a-positive-function-is-positive), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553031/integral-of-a-positive-function-is-positive), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351157/is-the-riemann-integral-of-a-strictly-positive-function-positive), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978692/if-the-lebesgue-integral-of-a-strictly-positive-function-is-zero).

Answer (score 4):

You are right.

Suppose $\int_0^1 f=0$.

Let $E_n=\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) > 1/n\}.$

$0=\int_0^1 f \geq \int_{E_n}f \geq \int_{E_n}(1/n)=m(E_n)(1/n)$

So $m(E_n)=0$ since $f>0 $ on $[0,1]$, $[0,1] = \cup E_n$ so $m([0,1])=0$.